# Stripe - retrieveCustomer callback infinite loading

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

I had implement the Stripe to my project.I'm using an extension of default `STPPaymentMethodsViewController` like this:

```
class PaymentMethodVC: STPPaymentMethodsViewController {

    convenience init()
    {
        let theme = STPTheme()
        theme.primaryBackgroundColor = UIColor.pintHubDarkBrown
        theme.secondaryBackgroundColor  = UIColor.pintHubHeaderColor


        theme.accentColor = UIColor.white
        theme.primaryForegroundColor = UIColor.pintHubOrange
        theme.secondaryForegroundColor = UIColor.pintHubOrange

        theme.font = UIFont.mainRegular()

        let paymentdelegate = PaymentMethodVCDelegate()
        let paymentConfig = STPPaymentConfiguration.shared()
        paymentConfig.publishableKey = "stripePublickToken"

        let apiAdapter = PaymentApiAdapter()

        self.init(configuration: paymentConfig, theme: theme, apiAdapter: apiAdapter, delegate: paymentdelegate)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

}
```

- `PaymentMethodVCDelegate` is an object that implements `STPPaymentMethodsViewControllerDelegate` that methods are never called and
- `PaymentApiAdapter` is other object that implements `STPBackendAPIAdapter` protocol which methods are:
  `public func retrieveCustomer(_ completion: @escaping Stripe.STPCustomerCompletionBlock) 
  public func attachSource(toCustomer source: STPSource, completion: @escaping Stripe.STPErrorBlock)
  public func selectDefaultCustomerSource(_ source: STPSource, completion: @escaping Stripe.STPErrorBlock)`

  everything works fine expect when i want to return an error to the callback method `func retrieveCustomer(_ completion: @escaping Stripe.STPCustomerCompletionBlock)` that is a method of the `STPBackendAPIAdapter` protocol more details [here](https://stripe.github.io/stripe-ios/docs/Protocols/STPBackendAPIAdapter.html#/c:objc(pl)STPBackendAPIAdapter(im)retrieveCustomer:).

this is my code:

```
func retrieveCustomer(_ completion: @escaping (STPCustomer?, Error?) -> Swift.Void)
    {
        stripeEndpoint.getStripeCustomer(for: "myStrypeCustomerId") { (status, JSON) in
            if !status.success()
            {
                let userInfo = [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:status.error,
                    NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey: status.code,
                    NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestionErrorKey: ""
                ] as [String : Any]

                let error = NSError(domain: "MyDomain", code: Int(status.error) ?? 0, userInfo: userInfo)
                completion(nil, error)
            }
            else
            {
                var customer:STPCustomer? = nil

                if let jsonData = JSON
                {
                    let deserializer = STPCustomerDeserializer(jsonResponse: jsonData)
                    customer = deserializer.customer!
                }

                completion(customer, nil)
            }
        }
```

and when i receive an error the screen displays and infinite loading indicator.

and if i call `completion(nil, nil)` the loading disappear but i when i press cancel the ViewController don't pop from stack

Comment: where you are started activity indicator ??.

Comment: is it working with success response ?

Comment: add code at where you are called this method .

Comment: just update the question, if you need more details i can add, but there is almost all

Comment: and func retrieveCustomer where called ?

Comment: retrieveCustomer is a protocol method of the `STPBackendAPIAdapter` that is implemented in `PaymentApiAdapter` object

Comment: ok then you have check there and hide activity indicator while got error  from response.

Comment: according to my thinking if you pass  completion(nil, nil) . it will be also not working because you dont have handled code while this kind of response returned .

Comment: if you are called this method where this issue faced i want that code here .